# Whatsapi send image works on local machine but not online

Tags: image, send, whatsapp

Hi I have a weird issue.

On my local machine I can send images no problem, when I upload (same code) , it does seem to send the image, but they actually never arrive at the destination.

Here is the debug: http://pastebin.com/TiMnpHxt

Any idea what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

In you local computer you are using xamp version 1.8.3 or upper version of that, and may be in your hosting server have a lower version of xamp or php version that is why